# Node -- node TypeError: options must be an object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting the error `TypeError: options must be an object`. I'm working through Chapter 4 of Node.js Design Patterns and on the State example.

At first I thought it was a typo on my part, but then I tried running the file with the book's code and got the same error.

```
var jot = require('json-over-tcp');
var server = jot.createServer(5000);

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data){
     console.log('Client data', data);
  });
});

server.listen(5000, function() {console.log('Started')});
```

I looked at the json-over-tcp example on NPM but can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you try removing the callback for `listen`, as in `server.listen(5000);`

Comment: Yeah and same result.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I tracked down json-over-tcp on Github (the one linked to on the NPM site doesn't exist anymore) and found the issue. The error I was getting is from the server.js file in json-over-tcp.

If I change the second line of my code to:

```
var server = jot.createServer({}, 5000);
```

it works fine--there just has to be options present. I guess the code in the book left that out.

Comment: Yeah, and for future reference most good libraries will normalize params such that an options object is, in fact, optional.  So the jot folks were just lazy, I guess.